# pass observable to another observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

the canActivate route event accepts a boolean observable.

I want to return from the authService.getUser() the user object which is instantiated or null.

Depending on the user value I want to return true/false to the boolean observable.

How can I do this?

```js
   canActivate() : Observable<boolean>
     {
        let userObservable = this.authService.getUser();
        userObservable.subscribe((user) => {
            if (user == null) {
                  this.authService.startSigninMainWindow();
                  return false;
            }
            else  
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
        return new Observable<boolean>("I want to pass here the 'future' result of the userObservable");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
return this.authService.getUser()
  .do(user => {
    if (user == null) { 
      this.authService.startSigninMainWindow();
    }
  })
  .map(user => !!user);
```

Comment: co00ol shit, thanks it worked! I need to learn all this rxjs stuff :P

Comment: I still made it:         .map<User,boolean>(user => !!user); so its easier for me to understand...

Comment: @HelloWorld `User,boolean` is not a correct type. It's conventional to use built-in Boolean as a predicate, `.map(Boolean)`.

Comment: Why is it not a correct type? User goes into the function and boolean value is returned.